# C: difference between 'struct Table *const' and 'const struct Table *'?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I created a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Table {
    #some members
  } Table;

typedef struct Table *TableP; // pointer to Table
```

And I want to use it in the following function (given to me)

```
int insert(const TableP table, const void *key, DataP object)
```

but Clion highlights table in the function, and gives the warning: "'table' declared with a const-qualified typedef type; results in the type being 'struct Table * const' instead of 'const struct Table *'"

I am not quite sure what this means. I tried changing my table struct to const but it doesn't change the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Difference Betweem `struct Table * const` and `const struct  Table*`?

`struct Table * const` means  `const pointer to struct Table`.

`const struct  Table*` means  `pointer to a struct Table which is constant`.

In the first case the pointer is constant but the `struct Table` is not. you can modify the table's attributes. But you can't change the pointer to point to different table.

Second case the pointer is non-constant. You can make it point to any struct table but if you try to modify the attribute of the initially pointed table it will throw error.

---

#### What did you do and why the error?

You have used `typedef struct Table *TableP;`. Now `const TableP` doesn't mean `const struct Table*`. It simply means `const pointer to a struct TableP` or `struct TableP* const`. That's what compiler said to you.

The solution would be to use `struct Table *const table` directly into the code when you are writing the function. This is what you want - here this means `table is a constant pointer to a struct Table`. Also this is much more readable and easy to use.

#### Extra points

This is why it's not a good idea to hide pointer behind `typedef` - it hampers readability and you run into some weird cases like this.

<sup>Note: The best way is to simply `typedef` the struct and pointer to it should be used directly.</sup>

```
typedef struct {
   ....
}Table;

void someFunc(Table *t);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1** :

```
typedef struct Table *TableP;
```

here `Tablep` is pointer to structure Table. When you are writing

`const TableP table`, it will be defined  like this  **const struct Table***

so what is meaning of `const struct Table*` , means address  `constant`, you can't change the address but you can modify it's members value .

for e.g

```
 struct Table {
  int x ;
  } v = {10}, v1 ={20};

typedef struct Table  *Tablep;
int main() {
        const Tablep table = &v ;//it becomes const pointer i.e you can't change address 
        table = &v1;// it's not possible.. address is contsant
       // table->x = 99;// possible.. can change it's member value

return 0;
}
```

Note : both `const Tablep local` and `Tablep const local` are same.

I hope it helps.

Comment: `const TableP table` declares `table` to be a `const` pointer to a `struct Table`, which is `struct Table * const`, not `const struct Table *`.

Comment: `const struct Table *` does not mean you cannot change the address but can change the members. It is the opposite; it is a changeable pointer to a constant structure.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if address is not constant then why `table = &v1` is giving error ? I hope by doing `table = &v1`  I am trying to change address .

Comment: As I wrote, `const TableP table` declares `table` to be a `const` pointer. (You used both `TableP` and `Tablep` in your answer, apparently not intending any difference between them. For consistency with the OP’s question, I will use the former.) Thus, in `table = &v1`, it attempts to change a pointer that is `const`, and hence it gets an error. I did not disagree with the code and the errors reported for it. I disagree with your statement “When you are writing `const TableP table`, it will be defined like this **const struct Table\***.” That is false. It will be `struct Table * const`.

Comment: Also, “so what is the meaning of `const struct Table*`, means address `constant`, you can’t change the address but you can modify it’s members value .” is false. `const struct Table*` means a non-const pointer to a const `struct Table`.

Comment: Okay @EricPostpischil agree with you. I will edit it. Thanks for pointing it.